# Are questions about martial arts films on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions concerning martial arts films, their stars, their directors, etc. on topic for this site?

My gut feeling is that some would be a better fit here and others would be a better fit for Movies.SE, which has [an existing tag for the martial arts genre](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/martial-arts).

Here are some hypothetical examples to consider:

- What kind of martial art is Tony Jaa's opponent using in the "burning temple" scene of The Protector (aka Tom-Yum-Goong)?
- How do they do all the crazy flying moves in kung fu movies?
- Is John Woo a martial artist?
- How accurate is the history and style of contemporary wing chun depicted in the Ip Man films made by Wilson Yip, Wong Kar-Wai and Herman Yau?

(In the interest of full disclosure, I'd like to ask that last one myself!)

Answer (score 6):

We've considered movies to be off-topic as per our [FAQ](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as we want to focus our site on actual martial arts and not theatrics. The first three questions are not good questions, because they are simple "identify this question" that would not elicit further discussion.

However, the last question you posed would be acceptable because it isn't necessarily about the movie itself but rather the martial art. That would be a question that would produce a well-researched answer diving into the history and characteristics of the style (which we do consider to be on-topic) to answer that question.